# Simple Mongoengine test gives error on Mac OSX

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm new to MongoDB, but comfortable with Python. I installed MongoDB with

```
brew install mongodb
```

then ran

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

then

```
sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
```

I installed `mongoengine` with

```
conda install -c conda-forge mongoengine
```

Then trying to follow the simple example at http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html, I ran made `test.py` that looks like this:

```
from mongoengine import *

connect('mongoengine-test')

class User(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True)

bob = User(email='bob@gmail.com')
bob.save()
```

and ran it with `python test.py`. I got this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 13, in <module>
    bob = User(email='bob@gmail.com')
  File "/Users/benlindsay/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._initialised = False
  File "/Users/benlindsay/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 169, in __setattr__
    self._is_document and
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '_is_document'
```

and looking up these errors online is giving me nothing.

I'm able to run `mongo` manually by first starting up `mongod` in one terminal, then running `mongo` in another. Using that method, all the commands I see in pure MongoDB tutorials seem to be available, but the simple python example breaks every time.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was some dependency issue. By creating a new conda environment and installing mongoengine with pip, everything worked fine.